# Getting an Error When Editing a Cell in a Table

Tags: sql-server, ssms

In Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, I was editing a table that I made from a query but I got this:

[image: error]

The data type I put in for that column was set as a `VARCHAR` but it reads as a byte. Any reason why this is?

Edit: My table looks like this:

[image: table]

and my query is this:

```
CREATE TABLE client_information (
    ClientID VARCHAR(6) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    AccountType VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    Address1 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Address2 VARCHAR(50),
    City VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    State VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    Zip VARCHAR(5)
);
```

The "Zip" column is where I get the error.

Comment: Can you post the table schema?

Comment: Need more details (your update statment, your column data type)

Comment: This looks like a bug in SSMS. What version of SSMS are you using? You can find the latest version of SSMS here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15 or previous versions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15#previous-ssms-releases. Note - it is best to install the newest version that matches your SQL Server version. If your SSMS is either too new or too old, it may not support all features that you would otherwise be able to use.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of SSMS but my server is 15.0.2000. Is there a way I can update the server version?

Comment: Quite simply - do NOT use SSMS as a data editing tool. As for upgrading - you should ask the person responsible for your server instance. If that is you, there is nothing preventing you from buying a newer paid edition or downloading a newer free edition.

Comment: And where exactly is a zip code less than 5 characters? THINK!